# Is there a way to distinguish the number of messages that have media without looping through each in PHP using Twilio's API?

Tags: php, twilio, message, twilio-php

Currently I'm using the query below to find all the messages a phone number has sent since a current date. I'd like to then be able to find out how many of those have media attached to them without looping through the entire list. It's super inefficient to loop through the whole list if it's huge. The "total" object works great to find the total number of messages but not sure how to distinguish. Is the a more efficient way to do this?

```
$lookup_vars = array('DateSent<' =>$renewal_date, 'From' => $row->conn_address);
$messages = $service->account->messages->getPage(0, 10, $lookup_vars);
// Get total messages
$messages->page->total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the only [filters that are present on the messages list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters) are currently `To`, `From` and `DateSent`. For now the best way to calculate this is to loop through the whole list. To make less calls to the API, you can increase the page size to 1000 records, which might make it slightly better.

To make this more efficient for yourself in the future, I'd suggest you save the details of what messages are sent within your system, then you will be able to query on them the way you want to.